# Remove Day, Date, year from Timestamp column in dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:
df1 =

```
Load      sort_begin                              comp_begin            
a         Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024             -                      
b        Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024            Mon Jan 15 23:23:58 PST 2024 
c        Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024            Mon Jan 15 23:17:58 PST 2024
```

How can we remove the day month year from timestamp in columns above and just timestamp in H:M:S format . Timestamps can be blank values or simply -( - ) ?

```
df2 = 
    Load      sort_begin                              comp_begin            
    a         23:17:58  PST                           -                      
    b         23:17:58 PST                           23:23:58 PST 
    c         23:17:58 PST                           23:17:58 PST
```

Is there any effective way to compute the time difference between `sort_begin` and `comp_begin` in seconds and add a new column

```
df3 = 
    Load      sort_begin                              comp_begin         diff     
    a         23:17:58  PST           -                                   -
    b         23:17:58 PST                           23:23:58 PST         xx sec
    c         23:17:58 PST                           23:17:58 PST         xx sec
```

Comment: I don't think there's a time datatype in pandas, just datetime. So you can't remove the date. You can use formatting functions to only show the time fields.

Comment: Why would you want to remove information from your data? Is this just about "prettier" visualization? Then you can create a new column for that. Keeping the full data (i.e. datetime objects) also allows you to easily comput time differences as you can just substract datetime objects to get the time difference.

Comment: Check [this conversion](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html)

Comment: @OskarHofmann: There is no need to remove. I just want to achieve df3, so I thought we can first convert to df2 and from df2 , subtract the columns to get df3. I am stuck to compute the time difference in seconds between sort_begin and comp_begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the columns to pandas datetime

```
df['sort_begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sort_begin'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PST %Y', errors='coerce')
df['comp_begin'] = pd.to_datetime(df['comp_begin'], format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S PST %Y', errors='coerce')
```

and then create a third column to calculate the difference in seconds

```
df['diff'] = (df['comp_begin'] - df['sort_begin']).dt.seconds
```

Output:

```
    load    sort_begin            comp_begin                 diff
0   a     2024-01-15 23:17:58     NaT                        NaN
1   b     2024-01-15 23:17:58     2024-01-15 23:23:58        360.0
2   c     2024-01-15 23:17:58     2024-01-15 23:17:58        0.0
```

Later you can remove the date part from `sort_begin` and `comp_begin`

```
df['sort_begin'] = df['sort_begin'].dt.time
df['comp_begin'] = df['comp_begin'].dt.time
```